# Qt QThread::run ends prematurely and crashes

Tags: c++, qt

I have a custom thread class that when ran, finishes up prematurely and ends up with a cryptic crash in some mangled-looking internal windows functions in the call stack. Here is my thread `run` method:

```
void MyThread::run()
{
    for(;;)
    {
       int result;
       QMutexLocker(&this->myMutex);
       query_result(&result);

       if(result == BAD_RESULT)
       {
           sleep(1);
           continue;
       }
       else
       {
           return;
       }
    }
}
```

And here is how I create and run it:

```
LoginThread myThread;
QEventLoop myLoop;
QTimer myTimer;

myTimer.setSingleShot(true);
connect(&myTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), &myLoop, SLOT(quit()));
connect(&myThread, SIGNAL(finished()), &myLoop, SLOT(quit()));

myTimer.start(120000);
myThread.start();
QApplication::setOverrideCursor(Qt::WaitCursor);
myLoop.exec(QEventLoop::ExcludeUserInputEvents);
QApplication::restoreOverrideCursor();
if(myTimer.isActive())
{
   myTimer.stop();
}
else
{
    //handle timeout
}
```

I have no idea why this is happening, this is query_result:

```
void query_result(int* result)
{
    if(result)
    {
        *result = some_global_integer;
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong that is causing the thread to terminate prematurely?

Comment: 1. Try running your program under Valgrind. 2. If it doesn't report any memory corruptions, provide an MVCE that may actually be compiled and run. 3. `QMutexLocker(&this->myMutex)` locks and immediately unlocks the mutex. Probably not what you want. Shouldn't cause any crashes, though.

Comment: What do you mean, doesn't it unlock it at the end of scope? Also I ran it under Valgrind and didn't find any corruption.

Comment: Which function is the myThread code creation in ?

Comment: 1. Since you create it as a temporary variable (no name), its scope is just one line. You should probably give it a name and put it in a separate block, like `{ QMutexLocker locker(&this->myMutex); query_result(&result); }`. 2. Provide a complete example along with Valgrind output.

Comment: Note that this->myMutex will be locked all the time the thread is sleeping. Does the the program reach the point at QApplication::restoreOverrideCursor(); when the event loop finished or it crashes earlier? And can you add debug output to each branch in run() to see what part was processed and how many times?

Comment: Do you really mean to re-implement the QThread class, or do you really just want to run some task in separate threads? If so that you should implement a normal class and use class.moveToThread mechanism (can point you in the right direction if needed), could save you some pain. Also is the purpose of the mutex just to protect `some_global_integer`? in this case you can move the mutex around the line `*result = some_global_integer;` inside the if block to reduce the scope of the mutex - pretty much everything Sergey and Evgeny (once you fix Sergey's issue) has mentioned regarding the mutex.

Comment: @Evgeny, why would it be locked all the time? As it is written now, it's unlocked immediately after locking. If the code is fixed as I suggested, the mutex-locking line and the call to `query_result` will be put into a separate block, and the mutex will be unlocked after exiting the block (i. e. before sleeping).

Comment: @SergeyTachenov The mutex will be unlocked only when the QMutexLocker is destroyed, i.e. when the thread leaves the scope of the cycle body. So, the only part where the mutex is not locked is the cycle condition check, but I guess there is just a jump for the infinite loop. And if you use that mutex in some other thread that thread will be probably frozen most of the time waiting on the locked mutex.

Comment: @Evgeny, the locker is destroyed immediately after its creation because it's created as a temporary variable. Look closely. It's not `QMutexLocker locker(...);`, it's `QMutexLocker(...)`. Create a simple class with constructor and destructor printing simple debugging messages and put it in place of the locker. You'll see that construction/destruction messages always come in pairs, simultaneously. This is certainly *not* how `QMutexLocker` is supposed to be used.

Comment: @SergeyTachenov I see. Yes, I missed that there is no variable. Sure, in this case it useless there.